Top and bottom alignment Swiftui
How to put a Header and Footer to the Top and Bottom of a View, respectively
I need the header and footer to stay at the top and bottom of a view, but I can't get it to work.
The view is this:
Scrollview {
    content
}

content is:
error()
VStack(spacing: 0) {
moreViews()
}

and error is:
VStack(alignment: .center) {
header
   .frame(alignment: .top)
Spacer()
footer
   .frame(alignment: .bottom)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
}


A Spacer doesn't work inside a ScrollView, nor does a maximum size of .infinity, unless you set a bounding frame around the content. This is because, content inside a ScrollView adopts its ideal size, just as if .fixedSize was applied.
To fix, try wrapping the ScrollView with a GeometryReader and set the minimum height of the content to the height of the ScrollView:
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        content
            .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)
    }
}


EDIT In your comment, you said that a white "empty view" is shown for a short period of time. To avoid this, you could always defer the setting of the minimum height, something like:
@State private var minContentHeight = CGFloat.zero

GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        content
            .frame(minHeight: minContentHeight)
            .onAppear {
                minContentHeight = proxy.size.height
            }
    }
}

Instead of using .onAppear, you could use .onChange and respond to some other state value changing.
Alternatively, you could switch content, depending on what is available to show. Something like:
if isLoaded {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            content
                .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)
        }
    }
} else {
    Text("Loading...")
}


Just in case you know, now, when the view "content" is being loaded, a white "empty view" is shown for a short period of time. Then, the correct view appeared (when "show" variable is checked I supposed). How can I avoid that first white empty view?
thanks!

Do you know any other way to do it?

@deslarry Answer updated with some suggestions for avoiding a white space during load
